# adding PK into another column when inserting

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I want to have the Primary Key inserted into another column using as below:-

```
Id  |  PaddedID |
----------------
6   |  0000006  |
7   |  0000007  |
```

Is there a way to achieve this in the db.SaveChanges() in one go? I know I can get the ID as below and update the PaddedID:-

```
int id = Result.Id;
```

Is there a way using LINQ to tell it take the PK pad it with some value and insert it in the PaddedID column?

Pointers appreciated....

Comment: Is `Id` server generated? I mean it could be `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE` driven

Comment: @JesúsLópez The Id is the column in the DB and is the Primary Key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a persistant computed column for PaddedID using the FORMAT integrated function, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD PaddedID AS FORMAT(Id, '00000000') PERSISTED
```

Comment: Getting below error :-Computed column 'PaddedID' in table 'Users' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

Have you use `HasComputedColumnSql` and try some thing like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<YouEntity>()
        .Property(p => p.PaddedID)
        // here is the computed query definition
        .HasComputedColumnSql("[Id]");
}
```

Comment: ``Is there a way using LINQ to tell it take the PK pad...`` it can be done with code first.